# Equivalent characterization of weak derivative in Bochner space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, integration, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a hilbert space. A function $v\in L_\text{loc}^1(0,T;H)$ is called the weak derivative of $u \in L_\text{loc}^1(0,T;H)$ iff
$$ \int_0^T u(t) \varphi'(t) \, dt = -\int_0^T v(t) \varphi(t) \, dt \quad \forall \varphi\in C_0^\infty(0,T). \tag{$*$} $$
Is this equivalent to
$$ \int_0^T (u(t),\Phi'(t))_H \, dt = -\int_0^T (v(t), \Phi(t))_H \, dt \quad \forall \Phi\in C_0^\infty(0,T;H) \text{?} \tag{$**$}$$

Since $(*)$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
& \int_0^T (u(t),\varphi'(t) z)_H \, dt \\[8pt] = {} & \left(\int_0^T u(t) \varphi'(t) \, dt, z\right)_H \\[8pt] = {} & -\left(\int_0^T v(t) \varphi(t) \, dt,z\right)_H \\[8pt] = {} & -\int_0^T (v'(t), \varphi(t) z)_H \, dt
\end{align}

for all $z\in H$ and $t\mapsto \varphi(t) z$ is a function in $C_0^{\infty}(0,T;H)$ with derivative $\varphi'(t) z$, $(**)$ immediatly implies $(*).$

Comment: Pick the particular $\Phi(t)(x) = \psi(t)h$ for any $\psi \in C_0^\infty(0,T)$ and $h \in H$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Doesn't this show the implication $(**)$ to $(*)$ which is already included in the post? Since $\psi$ is arbitrary and $\Phi$ is not.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I mixed it up. :-) But you can argue by density of $C_0^\infty(0,T) \otimes H$ in $C_0^\infty(0,T;H)$, see e.g. Amann: Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems Volume 1, Proposition V.2.4.1.

Comment: Thanks! If you change your comment to an answer, then I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can argue by density of $C_0^\infty(0,T)\otimes H$ in $C_0^\infty(0,T;H)$. A reference for that (probably there are more "natural" references but I do not know them) could be Herbert Amann: *Linear and Quasilinear Parabolic Problems, Volume 1*, Proposition V.2.4.1.